# Lombok intellij idea duplicate getter/setter methods and constructor generated

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a spring-boot project in intellij idea 2017.1 with lombok plugin installed and annotation processor enabled. When I build the project using **Build > Rebuild Project** I got    Compilation completed successfully. But In the Editor it stills show a compilation error on calling a getter method because of an ambiguous method call : in the structure of the class there are duplicate getter/setter methods.

Here is my class :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of having an another plugin installed which also does the lombok annotations processing, for example, Hrisey Plugin. Disabled that, and it would work!

Answer (score 0):

Intellij 2018 enabled "Hrisey Plugin" by default. Disabling the plugin fixes the problem.